# web app caching on JBOSS server - cache not used

Tags: java, caching, web-applications

everyone,

I seem to have a problem with the way my webapp handle brower cache. I tried to google it for a bit, but didn't find anything relevant.

To handle the cache, I put the following code in my web.xml :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Cache filter</filter-name> 
    <filter-class>My_personnal_class</filter-class> 
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Cache filter</filter-name> 
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

and use this class :

```
public class my_personnal_class implements Filter {

public void destroy() {}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)throws IOException,
ServletException {
    long time = 5 * 1000; // 5 secondes

    if (((HttpServletRequest)req).getRequestURI().indexOf("/a path/") != -1) {
        time= 20 * 60 * 1000; // 20 minutes
    }
    if (((HttpServletRequest)req).getRequestURI().indexOf("/yet another path/") != -1) {
        time= 20 * 60 * 1000; // 20 minutes
    }
    temps = temps + System.currentTimeMillis();
    ((HttpServletResponse)resp).setDateHeader("Expires", time);

    // Now let the request go through other filters and the servlet
    chain.doFilter(req, resp);
}

public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig)
throws ServletException {}
```

With that, I have indeed a cache expire date set to 20 minutes. (I can see it in the network tab of my trusty good old firebug.)

The problem is that the cache doesn't seem to be used. When I reload the page, instead of fetching the data in the cache, The server send me "304 - not modified" responses. 
Also, If I modify a resource (let's say an HTML page), the browser will go fetch it on the server (fully ! 200 response and I display the new version) even if the expiration date is not yet met.

I know 304 responses are not that of a big deal for a bandwith, but still .. I wonder if that behaviour is normal. Did I do (or understand) something wrong?

Any Info on that matter would be of a tremendous help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally got it, the above code was working alright.

When you reload a page, the browser will try to check each resources with the server. He'll then compare the cache cache content with what's on the serveur using the etag and issues 304 responses.

So, one should never test his http cache settings by reloading his page (f5). Just follow a link, or use a bookmark.

An easy-to-make mistake.